# Connes & Marcolli: Q-lattices generalize Conway's "Understanding groups like $\Gamma_0(N)$"

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, lattices

Has anyone generalized Conway's description of Hecke operators on lattices to the [Q-lattices of Connes & Marcolli](http://alainconnes.org/docs/Qlattices.pdf) ?

Light may well be shone on moonshine thus.